# Anyone had experience with .vbf fonts?

Tags: css, fonts

I really want to use this free font for embedding with @font-face: http://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/fonts/3-flaminia-type-system

However, it only comes in .vbf format. Has anyone ever dealt with this format before, or know how to convert it to a usable format? I can't find anything that will open it.

Comment: You might consider changing your question title to be a little more specific -- probably get better responses that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the page you linked states, it's the "[Multiple Master](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_master_fonts)" format. It seems there's free software available to convert Multiple Master fonts to PostScript fonts: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_master_fonts#Free_software.

Answer (score 1):

FontLab Studio saves font files as .vbf
This is not an installable font - this is font creation software. They need to be exported in the normal .otf and .ttf formats to be useable.